# How to identify which testing framework is being used

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

How to check whether in which testing framework, test cases are written
I don't want to check it manually but through a script, and when i get to know that. I can run the specific command of the framework to run the test files.
For example, if cypress is being used the i'll put up conditions and if its cypress then cypress.run() will be executed.

Comment: You have to put some sort of identifier on the tests for example " test_src " and read that before execution

Comment: can you give any example